# InvalidOperationException. The value is unknown when attempting to save changes

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have events and have users who can attend it. To link events with users i made a new  entity(table) as linking ref(m-m).

Now, i'm stuck a bit. While adding new user to an event, i receive exception: "The value of 'BoardZoneEventCustomer.BoardZoneEventId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known."

But before this problem, i was able to insert new row... Now it's broken. Spent a lot of time for solving it.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("enroll")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Enroll([FromBody] EventCustomerCreationDto eventCustomer)
{
    var eventCustomerAdd = _mapper.Map<EventCustomerDto>(eventCustomer);
    var eventCustomerCreated = await _eventCustomerService.AddAsync(eventCustomerAdd);

    return new ObjectResult(eventCustomerCreated) { StatusCode = 201 };
}
```

Service(for m-m table):

```
public async Task<EventCustomerDto> AddAsync(EventCustomerDto eventCustomerDto)
        {
            var customer = await _customerRepository.GetByIdAsync(eventCustomerDto.CustomerId);
            var eventId = await _eventRepository.GetIdAsync(eventCustomerDto.BoardZoneEventId);


            var bzEvent = new BoardZoneEventCustomer
            {
                Customer = customer,
                BoardZoneEvent = eventId
            };

            if (await _eventCustomerRepository.IsDublicated(eventCustomerDto.CustomerId, eventCustomerDto.BoardZoneEventId))
            {
                throw new CustomerDublicateEnrollingException("Already registered.");
            }

            await _eventCustomerRepository.AddAsync(bzEvent);

            return _mapper.Map<EventCustomerDto>(bzEvent);
        }
```

Forgot to post models:

```
public class EventCustomerCreationDto
    {
        public int BoardZoneEventId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    }

public class EventCustomerDto
    {
        public int BoardZoneEventId { get; set; }
        public BoardZoneEventDto BoardZoneEvent { get; set; }
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public CustomerDto Customer { get; set; }
    }
 public class BoardZoneEventDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int? MaxParticipantsNumber { get; set; }
        public int AlreadyRegisteredParticipants { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int FileEntityId { get; set; }
        public BoardZoneEventType EventType { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post BoardZoneEventCustomer class pls

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public async Task<EventCustomerDto> AddAsync(EventCustomerDto eventCustomerDto)
{

// I  moved this validation at the top where it makes sense

if (await _eventCustomerRepository.IsDublicated(eventCustomerDto.CustomerId, eventCustomerDto.BoardZoneEventId))
 {
  throw new CustomerDublicateEnrollingException("Already registered.");
 }

// ----- what do you need it for ????

            var customer = await _customerRepository.GetByIdAsync(eventCustomerDto.CustomerId);
            var eventId = await _eventRepository.GetIdAsync(eventCustomerDto.BoardZoneEventId);

//--------------


            var bzEvent = new BoardZoneEventCustomer
            {
                CustomerId = eventCustomerDto.CustomerId,
                BoardZoneEventId = eventCustomerDto.BoardZoneEventId
            };


            await _eventCustomerRepository.AddAsync(bzEvent);
            return  eventCustomerDto;


           //  why do you need to map it?
           return _mapper.Map<EventCustomerDto>(bzEvent);
        }
```